# Gatsby, Stripe: Creating a button source code returns 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'configure' of undefined'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, stripe-payments, gatsby

I'm building an e-commerce site based on a tutorial entry from [here](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/ecommerce-tutorial/#setting-up-a-serverless-function-in-aws-lambda).

But, from a source code for checkout.js returns these errors and the entire page is all white out.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'configure' of undefined
The above error occurred in the <Checkout> component:
The above error occurred in the <LocationProvider> component:
GET http://localhost:8000/.../src/components/checkout.js 404 (Not Found)
```

I see lots of `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'configure' of undefined` and 404 error the most.

Tried to see with writing CSS-in-JS library, styled-components because I use for this project.
A difference is, favicon shows and before with all exactly same source code from a tutorial was not even showing favicon.

An error message changed into this.

```
Uncaught Error: Thestyleprop expects a mapping from style properties to values, not a string. For example, style={{marginRight: spacing + 'em'}} when using JSX.
```

**Relevant information:**

Also, I tested with making index.js with exactly same code in tutorial, but the results are the same as in above.
When I disable checkout.js component, it works perfectly, means I bet checkout.js code has the highest potential to be fixed.

src/components/checkout.js

```
import React from "react"

// hardcoded amount (in US cents) to charge users
// you could set this variable dynamically to charge different amounts
const amount = 2500
const cardStyles = {
  display: "flex",
  flexDirection: "column",
  justifyContent: "space-around",
  alignItems: "flex-start",
  padding: "3rem",
  boxShadow: "5px 5px 25px 0 rgba(46,61,73,.2)",
  backgroundColor: "#fff",
  borderRadius: "6px",
  maxWidth: "400px",
}
const buttonStyles = {
  fontSize: "13px",
  textAlign: "center",
  color: "#fff",
  outline: "none",
  padding: "12px 60px",
  boxShadow: "2px 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.1)",
  backgroundColor: "rgb(255, 178, 56)",
  borderRadius: "6px",
  letterSpacing: "1.5px",
}

// Below is where the checkout component is defined.
// It has several functions and some default state variables.
const Checkout = class extends React.Component {
  state = {
    disabled: false,
    buttonText: "BUY NOW",
    paymentMessage: "",
  }

  resetButton() {
    this.setState({ disabled: false, buttonText: "BUY NOW" })
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.stripeHandler = window.StripeCheckout.configure({
      // You’ll need to add your own Stripe public key to the `checkout.js` file.
      // key: 'pk_test_STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY',
      key: "pk_test_testtesttesttesttesttest",
      closed: () => {
        this.resetButton()
      },
    })
  }

  openStripeCheckout(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    this.setState({ disabled: true, buttonText: "WAITING..." })
    this.stripeHandler.open({
      name: "Demo Product",
      amount: amount,
      description: "A product well worth your time",
      token: token => {
        fetch(`AWS_LAMBDA_URL`, {
          method: "POST",
          mode: "no-cors",
          body: JSON.stringify({
            token,
            amount,
          }),
          headers: new Headers({
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          }),
        })
          .then(res => {
            console.log("Transaction processed successfully")
            this.resetButton()
            this.setState({ paymentMessage: "Payment Successful!" })
            return res
          })
          .catch(error => {
            console.error("Error:", error)
            this.setState({ paymentMessage: "Payment Failed" })
          })
      },
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div style={cardStyles}>
        <h4>Spend your Money!</h4>
        <p>
          Use any email, 4242 4242 4242 4242 as the credit card number, any 3
          digit number, and any future date of expiration.
        </p>
        <button
          style={buttonStyles}
          onClick={event => this.openStripeCheckout(event)}
          disabled={this.state.disabled}
        >
          {this.state.buttonText}
        </button>
        {this.state.paymentMessage}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Checkout
```

pages/index.js

```
import React from "react"
import Helmet from "react-helmet"
import Favicon from "../components/fav-nma.png"
import Container from "../components/container"
import Layout from "../components/layout"
import Top from "../components/top"
//import Mainbody from "../components/mainbody"
import Apply from "../components/apply"
import Checkout from "../components/checkout"
import Price from "../components/price"
import Footer from "../components/footer"

const IndexPage = () => (
  <Layout>
    <Helmet link={[
      { rel: 'shortcut icon', type: 'image/png', href: `${Favicon}` }
  ]}>
      <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
      <meta property="og:url" content="test" />
      <meta property="og:title" content="test" />
      <meta property="og:description" content="test" />
      <meta property="og:image" content="test" />
      <meta property="fb:app_id" content="test" />
      <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image" />
      <meta name="twitter:title" content="test" />
      <meta name="twitter:description" content="test" />
      <meta name="twitter:image" content="test" />
    </Helmet>
    <Container>
      <Top />
      <Apply />
      <div>
        <Checkout />
      </div>
      <Price />
      <Footer />
    </Container>
  </Layout>
)

export default IndexPage
```

Comment: Can you please post your code... the 404 error is a page not found error. Could be from transpiring, or wrong file path...

Comment: Can you post your code where the checkout.js is used?

Comment: Hi Pari Baker, wsw.
I added code in above. It used to be fine without checkout.js and when I remove it, it goes back to no errors. 
I bet there could be a file path issue from what you told me 404, but I don't know where exactly...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'configure' of undefined` indicates that you didn't load `StripeCheckout`.

As the tutorial that you are following suggests, add the stripe checkout script to your document.

```
<script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js"></script>
```

You can place this in the `<head>` of your html document or right below the closing `</html>` tag.

---

Additionally, you can use https://github.com/stripe/react-stripe-elements instead which allows you to manage the dependency within your package.json and `import` it within your code.

Its usage is slightly different, but their documentation is fantastic.

Comment: Hi Seth.
Do you mean to add that in a public/index.html, or pages/index.js?
I tried both but both are not working neither.

Comment: It would need to go wherever your `head` lives or wherever you close your `html` tag.

Comment: It perfectly worked! I added into public/index.html's right after </html> and suddenly popped out. 
Thank you so much!

Btw, I checked react-stripe-elements but I do not see yet what's better to add this for Gatsby project. (Forgive my poor understanding of what you explained to me)
Does this work with same say as it described in their documentation...?

Comment: The react library works similarly to the Gatsby tutorial that you're working on. Though, I'd suggest continue working with what you have now that's its operating properly.

Comment: Make sense, now, I got why you gave me that advice. Thank you for your help. It really made my day.

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurs during build because 'window' is not a valid object in line 2 of this snippet:

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.stripeHandler = window.StripeCheckout.configure({
    key: "pk_test_testtesttesttesttesttest",
    closed: () => {
      this.resetButton()
    },
  })
}
```

'window' doesn't exist while Gatsby builds the static assets for your site. This occurs when you run `Gatsby serve` or `gastby build` or when you deploy to Netlify (or wherever).

To avoid this problem during build, wrap that line in an if statement to check whether `window` exists.

```
componentDidMount() {
  if (typeof window !== `undefined`) {
    this.stripeHandler = window.StripeCheckout.configure({
      key: `pk_test_testtesttesttesttesttest`,
      closed: () => {
        this.resetButton()
      }
    })
  }
}
```

I stole this info from: https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/debugging-html-builds/